# Flexbox contents not rendering in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to create a flexbox in React, inside of which I want to place to two divs, one on top of the other. I'm having trouble getting the content of the two divs to render. Right now, I have:

```
class Flexbox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-5" style={{flex: 1, alignItems:'center'}}>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

class DivOne extends Component {
  render() {
    return (  
      <div>
        <p>
          Welcome!
        </p>
      </div>  
    );
  }
}

class DivTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (  
      <div>
        <p>
           Some text here
        </p>
      </div>  
    );
  }
}

class Final extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <Flexbox>
                <DivOne />
                <DivTwo />
              </Flexbox>

              <AnotherComp />
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I put all of DivOne and DivTwo's contents into the flexbox's main div, I can see my text. I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly when I'm passing children into Flexbox.

Comment: You're missing `this.props.children`. Read: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: In Flexbox return the other two components that you want, inside the `<div className="col-lg-5"`

Comment: Something like this (just a example) https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/xhetdnsa/ . Checkout this too, react with flexbox: http://jsfiddle.net/bswisher/6xxaynn3/